# VS Code, navigate within a wrapped line vs jumping to next line

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vs code I've noticed that when line wrap is enabled using the arrow keys to go to the next line causes the cursor to skip over any wrapped content and go to the next editor line.  Is there any way to make navigation go to the next visual line instead? Given the below snippet: if my cursor is on the t of this in line 1 and I hit down, is there a way to have the cursor go to the a in automatically rather than the t in this on line 2?

```
1 this is a line that
  automatically wraps 
2 this is another line
3
```

Comment: Do you have the vim extension installed, or other extensions that might impact this? You can try launching with `--disable-extensions`

Comment: @RobLourens Yes, I do use the vscodevim extension.  I tried turning it off and now I have the expected behavior.  I'd like j and w to have the above described behavior with the extension turned on, do you know if that's possible?  I've tried looking at the vscodevim docs and suspect that it may have something to do with keybindings, but am not sure.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Evidently the issue I was facing was VIM specific standard behavior.  At some point I must have used a vim implementation that defaulted j and k to gj and gk respectively.  I was able to recreate this behavior by adding the following to my vs-code options:

```
  "vim.otherModesKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        "before": ["j"],
        "after": ["g", "j"]
    },
    {
        "before": ["k"],
        "after": ["g", "k"]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: @ifconfig Yes, they go in the settings.json.

Comment: If anyone else wants more information on this like I did, it is explained more here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Move_cursor_by_display_lines_when_wrapping

Comment: To get the arrow keys to move down and up visual lines as well, you can add these configuration objects:

    {
      "before": [
        "down"
      ],
      "after": [
        "g",
        "j"
      ]
    },
    {
      "before": [
        "up"
      ],
      "after": [
        "g",
        "k"
      ]
    }

Comment: The option key has been changed to `vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive`.

Answer (score 11):

It seems that the `vim.otherModesKeyBindingsNonRecursive` setting now is gone and I use this instead:

```
  "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        "before": ["j"],
        "after": ["g", "j"]
    },
    {
        "before": ["k"],
        "after": ["g", "k"]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Not super important, but I think that `normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive` is standard from what I noticed. Not sure that it matters.

And just as a side comment, the answer from above no longer works as OA says, but still goes inside the settings.json file! 

Thanks for the help Alexey Zimarev!

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to achieve the same thing in visual mode? I tried the exact same bindings but replacing "normal" with "visual", but this does not seem to work.